# Can't find Mac OS x 64 bit on virtual machine?

Tags: windows, macos, operating-system, 64-bit, virtual-machine

my virtual machine can't find an option for mac OS 64 bit, i'm trying to run a leopard on it but I can't find a section for the 64 bit mac.

Comment: @JosephS.Khella-Which virtual machine are you using---VMware workstation/Player,Oracle's VirtualBox?

Comment: @shekharsuman i'm using oracle virtualbox version 4.3.12r93733

Comment: Which OS options are you able to figure out,like Windows 7/8,Linux,Solaris,etc.???

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by:
1. reinstalling/repaire the latest version of VirtualBox.
2. ***restarting*** the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Oracle VirtualBox" which is an open source virtualization tool and  iATKOS ML2 (Mountain Lion 10.8.2 PC) which is a simple and all-in-one OSX86 installation for basic and compatible hardware.

Visit http://iatkos.me/forum/viewtopic.php?f=77&t=23105 for further details.